# Shell kill hanging script after timeout but cancel timeout if script doesn't hang

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tcsh

I'm working in **tcsh** (sigh) and I'd like to implement scenario described in the title. I've come up with partially ok solution down below. It starts script_1.sh and kills it after timeout. That works ok if script_1.sh hangs, but if it finishes before timeout, script_2.sh will still have to wait before timeout happens and I'd like to start script_2.sh immediately.

```
setenv timeout 2000

/home/$USER/script_1.sh &

sleep $timeout
kill -9 $!

/home/$USER/script_2.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a temporary file to signal that `script1` is done:

```
setenv timeout 2000

/home/$USER/script_1.sh && echo > /tmp/script1_done &

sleep $timeout

if ( ! -f /tmp/script1_done ) then
    kill -9 $!
endif
rm /tmp/script1_done

/home/$USER/script_2.sh
```

---

Note that with a "real" programming language (pretty much *any* language) this sort of stuff becomes a lot easier, for example in Python's `subproccess` module there's simply a `timeout` setting :-)

Comment: This implements solution which checks whether script_1 finished after `$timeout` seconds, however I'd like to cancel timer if script_1 finishes before timeout. I've found solution in form of `timeout` Unix command explained [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html). I encapsulated command within script which has potential to hang in `timeout` command.